# WebStorm/Intellij Gherkin tests configuration run

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, gherkin

How to set up running configuration with WebStorm feature file?

When I click on green run button seems that WebStorm can't find the steps realisation.

How could I change that WebStorm understands from where should it take steps?

When I run tests with command line it works, I have config file where I declared steps folder.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `--require path/to/step/definitions` as **Cucumber.js arguments:** field:

[image]

Comment: it is creating good config, but when I click on green button 'run' next to feature it runs with new fresh config and the one I created is not used.
Can you please suggest on that?

Comment: you can add these parameters to **Cucumber.js** configuration [template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.1/run-debug-configuration.html#templates)